# Expo - Incompatible SDK version or no SDK version specified

Tags: react-native, expo

I can not begin with my simulator anymore. All my iphone and simulator returns error below. And im very tired development on Expo.

when i command

```
npx expo start
```

it returns that error.

[image]

my app.json file is like below:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    },
```

I can not connect my phone, i can not start it on emulator, i can not debug anything. whats wrong? what could be wrong?